# pip3 изменить интерпретатор

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Недавно обновил Ubuntu. Вместе с ним загрузилась новая версия python 3.6 (была python 3.5). Теперь не могу установить новые модули, т.к pip3 ссылается на предыдущую версию питона которого уже нет.

Comment: Предположу, что у вас установлен кастомный pip, попробуйте `/usr/bin/pip3 uninstall pip` (без рута, чтоб системный pip не удалить)

Comment: Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr

Comment: Ладно, а вообще что тогда `which pip3` пишет?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: Значит у вас pip какой-то левый всё-таки, однако как теперь корректно вернуть всё на место я уже не в курсе

Comment: просто удали /usr/local/bin/pip3 и поставь пип из пакета

Comment: попробуйте использовать virtualenv

Comment: Проблема решилась сама собою путем обновление нескольких пакетов